# Large quantity of data on JavaScript and HTML leads to the "Page unresponsive" dialogue in XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, html, xampp

I have to write a program using PHP, HTML, and JavaScript. The program must generate 1 Million random license plates and display them in a text field.
Also the program should keep track of plates per province.
I used the script below, but when I try to generate more than 10000, I get a "Page unresponsive" dialogue in XAMPP.
I am wondering if there isn't a simpler way to do this? Thank you!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form generate licence plates</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//The letters available for use.
arrLetters = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']
//The province codes available for use.
arrProvCode = ['CA', 'ZN', 'MP', 'EC', 'L', 'GP', 'NC', 'FS', 'NW']
arrGenLetters = []
arrGenNumbers = []
arrGenNumberPlates=[]
var GenProvCode = ""; //The random generated province code

var countCA = 0;
var countZN = 0;
var countMP = 0;
var countEC = 0;
var countL = 0;
var countGP = 0;
var countNC = 0;
var countFS = 0;
var countNW = 0;


function GenerateAndAddtext() 
{
//Repeat 1M times.
for(k=0; k<1000000; k++)
{
    //Generate 3 random letters & add to array.
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
    var min=0; 
    var max=20;  
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
    arrGenLetters[j] = arrLetters[randomNumber];
    }   
    //Generate 3 random numbers & add to array.
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
    var min=0; 
    var max=9;  
    var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
    arrGenNumbers[i] = randomNumber2;
    }   
    //Generate the random province code.
    var min=0; 
    var max=9;  
    var randomNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
    var GenProvCode = arrProvCode[randomNumber3];
    //Count the province codes per province.
    if(GenProvCode == "CA")
    {
        ++countCA
    }
    if(GenProvCode == "ZN")
    {
        ++countZN
    }
    if(GenProvCode == "MP")
    {
        ++countMP
    }
    if(GenProvCode == "EC")
    {
        ++countEC
    }
    if(GenProvCode == "L")
    {
        ++countL
    }
    if(GenProvCode == "GP")
    {
        ++countGP
    }
    if(GenProvCode == "NC")
    {
        ++countNC
    }
    if(GenProvCode == "FS")
    {
        ++countFS
    }
    if(GenProvCode == "NW")
    {
        ++countNW
    }

    arrGenNumberPlates[k] = arrGenLetters[0] + arrGenLetters[1] + arrGenLetters[2] + "-" + arrGenNumbers[0] + arrGenNumbers[1] + arrGenNumbers[2] + "-" +GenProvCode;
    }

    for(v=0; v<1000000; v++)
    {
    document.OutputForm.GeneratedPlates.value += arrGenNumberPlates[v]+ "\n";
    }

    document.OutputForm.Gauteng.value = countGP;
    document.OutputForm.Mpumalanga.value = countMP;
    document.OutputForm.Limpopo.value = countL;
    document.OutputForm.WesternCape.value = countCA;
    document.OutputForm.KwaZuluNatal.value = countZN;
    document.OutputForm.EasternCape.value = countEC;
    document.OutputForm.FreeState.value = countFS;
    document.OutputForm.NorthenCape.value = countNC;
    document.OutputForm.NorthWest.value = countNW;

}
</script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form name="OutputForm">
        <input type="button" value="Generate" onClick="GenerateAndAddtext();"><br>
        <textarea name="GeneratedPlates" cols="80" rows="30"></textarea><br>
        <label>Gauteng<input type="text" name="Gauteng"></label><br>
        <label>Mpumalanga<input type="text" name="Mpumalanga"></label><br>
        <label>Limpopo<input type="text" name="Limpopo"></label><br>
        <label>Western Cape<input type="text" name="WesternCape"></label><br>
        <label>KwaZulu-Natal<input type="text" name="KwaZuluNatal"></label><br>
        <label>Eastern Cape<input type="text" name="EasternCape"></label><br>
        <label>Free State<input type="text" name="FreeState"></label><br>
        <label>Northen Cape<input type="text" name="NorthenCape"></label><br>
        <label>North West<input type="text" name="NorthWest"></label><br>
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't think anybody is going to browse 1MM records. You can generate them and store them in the data base, then show them in chunks on 50 by paginating the result.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I considered but the Assignment says: "When the button is clicked, generate 1M random plates, and display them in a text area" . So to achieve maximum marks, there has to be 1M random plates in my text area...

Comment: Using ajax you could trick the solución. Set a fixed height to the text box with overflow scroll, fill it with the first 50 plates, when the scroll is reaching the bottom bring in the next 50 and append them to the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should minimize the amount of processes as below:

1 - Remove the variable definition into your `for` loop. You don't have to set it in every loop. Just set it once before the loop.

From

```
for(j=0; j<3; j++)
{
    var min=0; 
    var max=20;  
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
    arrGenLetters[j] = arrLetters[randomNumber];
}
```

To

```
var min=0; 
var max=20; 
for(j=0; j<3; j++)
{ 
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
    arrGenLetters[j] = arrLetters[randomNumber];
}
```

2 - Remove duplicated loop when there is no reason to do it. For this purpose create 2 `max` variables.

From

```
//Generate 3 random letters & add to array.
for(j=0; j<3; j++)
{
    var min=0; 
    var max=20;  
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
    arrGenLetters[j] = arrLetters[randomNumber];
}
//Generate 3 random numbers & add to array.
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    var min=0; 
    var max=9;  
    var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
    arrGenNumbers[i] = randomNumber2;
}
//Generate the random province code.
var min=0;
var max=9;
```

To

```
//Generate 3 random letters & add to array.
var min = 0, max = 9, max2 = 20;
for(j=0; j<3; j++)
{ 
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max2 - +min)) + +min; 
    arrGenLetters[j] = arrLetters[randomNumber];
    var randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min; 
    arrGenNumbers[j] = randomNumber2;
}
```

3 - Use `if` and `else if` instead multiple `if`. It will stop when the condition will be met instead to continue to verify every other conditions for now reason. You might consider `switch` as well as there are a lot of `if`.

From

```
if(GenProvCode == "CA")
{
    ++countCA
}
if(GenProvCode == "ZN")
{
    ++countZN
}
if(GenProvCode == "MP")
{
    ++countMP
}
if(GenProvCode == "EC")
{
    ++countEC
}
if(GenProvCode == "L")
{
    ++countL
}
if(GenProvCode == "GP")
{
    ++countGP
}
if(GenProvCode == "NC")
{
    ++countNC
}
if(GenProvCode == "FS")
{
    ++countFS
}
if(GenProvCode == "NW")
{
    ++countNW
}
```

To

```
if(GenProvCode == "CA")
{
    ++countCA
}
else if(GenProvCode == "ZN")
{
    ++countZN
}
else if(GenProvCode == "MP")
{
    ++countMP
}
else if(GenProvCode == "EC")
{
    ++countEC
}
else if(GenProvCode == "L")
{
    ++countL
}
else if(GenProvCode == "GP")
{
    ++countGP
}
else if(GenProvCode == "NC")
{
    ++countNC
}
else if(GenProvCode == "FS")
{
    ++countFS
}
else if(GenProvCode == "NW")
{
    ++countNW
}
```

4 - Concatenate `1000000` values first then inject it. Otherwise the process will be to heavy.

From

```
for(v=0; v<1000000; v++)
{
    document.OutputForm.GeneratedPlates.value += arrGenNumberPlates[v]+ "\n";
}
```

To

```
myValue = '';
for(v=0; v<1000000; v++)
{
    myValue += arrGenNumberPlates[v]+ "\n";
}
document.OutputForm.GeneratedPlates.value += myValue;
```

Hopefully, it would be optimized as you wish, otherwise please let me know, there is a ton of solution to keep increasing the speed. Let me know if you have any comment, feedback or question please.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advice but XAMPP gave the same error in the end. After I waited a few seconds though, it responded and worked. This is already a massive improvement!

Comment: My pleasure! Anytime!